# Dimensionamento do texto automático C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Gostaria de saber se é possível que um texto dentro de um form possa ter o tamanho da fonte alterada de acordo com o tamanho do form para ficar sempre proporcional

Comment: use o evento `Form.ResizeEnd` que será ativado quando redimensionar o form, assim pode pegar a medida do form e mudar o tamanho da fonte para um valor "proporcional"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sim, é possível alterar o tamanho da fonte de um texto de acordo com o tamanho do formulário (form) em que ele está inserido. Você pode fazer isso por meio do evento de redimensionamento (resize) do formulário e ajustando o tamanho da fonte do texto de acordo com o tamanho atual do formulário.

```
{
    float fontSize = (float)(this.Width * 0.05); // ajuste este valor de acordo com a proporção desejada
    textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily, fontSize);
}
```

O valor de 0,05 na linha float fontSize = (float)(this.Width * 0.05); é um valor de proporção que pode ser ajustado para a proporção desejada. Se você deseja que o tamanho da fonte aumente mais rapidamente à medida que o formulário é redimensionado, pode aumentar esse valor.